# How to prioritize IIS URL rewriting rules?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Is it possible to make URL rewriting rules executing with a specified priority order (i.e. one rules before another)?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your code, you manage it with your code.
i use "if else" structures and rewritepath method in my application_request event and manage my url rewriting.

but if you had some regular roles, so use the roles in web.config.

sometimes you had somthing like that

```
www.yoursite.com/products/34
```

and you want to rewite it into

```
 www.yoursite.com/products.aspx?id=34
```

in these cases i offer to use the role in web.config.
but sometime it not as easily as this one.so use the  application_request method and because you manually rewrite you path you can change their priority.

finally :

my offer is use the application_request event and rewrite your urls in this special case ;-)

if need more help comment then i will edit this answer dude.